# Nginx Ubuntu 16.10 install error

Tags: nginx

can somebody help me out when installing nginx on Ubuntu 16.10 version, thanks a lot.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Try running `apt-get update` and then try reinstalling

Comment: Still occur the same error, always said (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case i would do:
 1. apt-get remove nginx* --purge
 2. apt-get autoremove
 3. apt-get update
 4. apt-get install nginx

Comment: Still occur the same error, always said (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: maybe you have dpkg running thats why it exits. can you check ps -aux | grep dpkg ? if something is running , kill it with kill -9 PID

Comment: i have solved the problem, actually there is a syntax on my conf file, i did realize that it will run on the config file once the nginx is started.